# Running Exec() Command Parameter

Tags: c, linux

I am student developer and beginner in C programming language. I have a task and I did not find a clear solution according to my level. I want to run exec() function in child process. I created parent and child using fork(). It's OK. But my code is only running command like `ls , pwd` etc. If I want to write `ls -l`, it does not work command like that. What should I do ? Could you help me at this issue ?

My output for  `ls` :

> ls
>   a.out  main.c
>   2006152 ms

My output for `ls -l`:

> ls -l
>   Error exec: No such file or directory
>   3627824 ms

My code is :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

void ChildProcess  ();  
void ParentProcess ();  

struct timeval start, end;

int main () {


    gettimeofday (&start, NULL);

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork ();

    if (pid == 0){
        ChildProcess ();
    }
    else {
        wait (NULL);
        ParentProcess ();
    }

return 0;
}

void ChildProcess () {
    char input[N];
    scanf (" %[^\n]s", input);

    if (execlp (input, "", (char *) 0) < 0){
    perror ("Error exec");
    exit (0);}
} 

void ParentProcess () {
    gettimeofday (&end, NULL);
    printf ("%ld %s \n", ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec)-(start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)), "ms");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to run a program called `ls -l`, not a program called `ls` with an argument of `-l`.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `(char *)0` instead of `NULL`? I mean, the C standard dictates that 0 (of any kind) and NULL will be evaluated the same, but I just find it to be a somewhat disputable practice.

Comment: regarding: `scanf (" %[^\n]s", input);`   This is expecting a literal 's' in the input `stdin`  Not what you want.  Suggest:  `if( scanf( " %[^\n]", input ) != 1 ) {  //handle error  and exit }`

Comment: regarding: `if (pid == 0){
        ChildProcess ();
    }
    else {
        wait (NULL);
        ParentProcess ();`  this, when `fork()` fails, will call `wait()` with no child process.  This is a problem that you need to fix.  Suggest using: `switch( pid ) { case -1: perror( "fork failed: ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); break;  case 0:  ChildProcess(); break;  default: wait(); ParentProcess();  break; }`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `if (execlp (input, "", (char *) 0) < 0){`  The `exec..()` functions ONLY return if an error occurred.  Suggest: `execlp (input, "", (char *) 0); perror( "execlp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: in general, exiting with 0 indicates success, but in the child process, this call to `exit()` is due to an error.  Suggest using: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `void ChildProcess  ();` and `void ParentProcess ();`  This is NOT a good method of declaring a function prototype when the function does not take any parameters.  Suggest: `void ChildProcess  ( void );` and `void ParentProcess ( void );`  Notice the use of `void` between the parens, so the compiler produces code that does not expect any parameters, unlike () which allows any number and kind of parameters (and it'd usage is frowned upon)

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  it is missing the statement: `#include <time.h>` to expose the prototype for function: `gettimeofday()`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that all `exec()` family functions expect *only* the executable name as the first parameter (without any arguments). The arguments are then passed according to the `exec` function you decided to call. In the case of `execlp()`, all the arguments  (including the executable name) are passed as a null-terminated list.

Essentially, you want to call your function in this way:

```c
execlp ("ls", "ls", "-l", (char *) 0);
```

The way to do this is by splitting the `input` string on the space character (using `strtok()`) and saving the results in different variables.

If you would like to handle however cases of multiple arguments, then you cannot achieve it by using `execlp()`. Use `execvp()` instead with the according modifications. You can find the man page for all `exec()` functions [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) which will give you enough information.

Comment: I understand. When I add it, my project runs `ls -l` . But I want to take an input value from user. What should I do ? How can I use inside your code sample ? Or is it possible ? @kyriakosSt